# (Raspbian + C# + Mono) Type initializer for 'System.Device.Gpio.Drivers.LibGpiodDriver' threw an exception

Tags: c#, mono, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm conducting a preliminary study for a new project. I've purchased a Raspberry Pi 3B and I'm trying to run a small program to check all our requisites:

1. SQL Server connection.
2. Save configuration files on disk.
3. Configure and use some DI/DO in Raspberry GPIO.

By now I've installed Mono libraries on it and I'm using Visual Studio 2019 in my windows machine to build a WinForms application.

```
Raspberry OS version: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Mono version        : Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0.122
```

And these are the packages of my application: (.Net Framework 4.8)

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Device.Gpio" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.AccessControl" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Principal.Windows" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>
```

By now I have nothing connected to the GPIO, I'm just trying to read a pin value using this code:

```cs
private void ReadPinTest()
{
    int pin = 24;
    PinValue pinValue = PinValue.Low;

    try
    {
        using (GpioController gpio = new GpioController(PinNumberingScheme.Board))
        {
            if (gpio == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No GPIO controller found.");
                return;
            }

            gpio.OpenPin(pin, PinMode.Input);
            pinValue = gpio.Read(pin);
        }

        MessageBox.Show($"Pin {pin} is {pinValue}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting next errors:

**Exception message:**

> Type initializer for 'System.Device.Gpio.Drivers.LibGpiodDriver' threw an exception.

**InnerException message:**

> libgpiod

**InnerException StackTrace:**

> at(wrapper managed - to - native) Interop + libgpiod.gpiod_version_string()
> at System.Device.Gpio.Drivers.LibGpiodDriver.IsLibgpiodVersion1_5orHigher() [0x00000] in < d49ca6cd97194f038905958dbca2c58c >:0
> at System.Device.Gpio.Drivers.LibGpiodDriver..cctor ()[0x0000f] in :0

I've tried by reinstalling gpiod libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install gpiod
```

> gpiod is already the newest version (1.2-3+rpi1).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using .NET 5.0 when targeting linux/raspbian. The support for linux has been greatly improved in this version, while the future of Mono is uncertain. It does not officially have Gui support yet, but you can either use Avalonia or try the [Maui-Linux](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/maui-linux) package, which will eventually make it into .NET 6.0 (which is scheduled for this fall).

Your particular problem is probably solved by running

```
sudo apt install -y libgpiod-dev
```

However, System.Device.Gpio has not been deeply tested against mono, because it is mostly targeting .NET Core. .NET Framework support is for Windows.

Comment: I've installed `libgpiod-dev` and it works with .NetFramework 4.8. I'll try with Net Core too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

WinForms is only designed to run on Windows. It may work with Mono, but you would probably want to compile it on a Windows machine. It seems that Mono is, as of now, supporting up to .NET Framework 4.7 — so this is probably where the message comes from.

If you don't want to compile on Windows, try targeting 4.7 or use dotnet core and write a command line app to test your backend requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately I need a graphical interface. But I'll try targeting Net Framework 4.7. BTW I'm using a windows machine to compile as I explained in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this part. But if you need a graphical interface, you can try a mono compatible one like Gtk#.